# Test Javascript across multiple browsers

Tags: javascript, testing, jenkins

I am investigating frameworks to automate testing of javascript application different browsers: IE, Chrome, Firefox etc. I would like to include it as part of my Jenkins CI pipeline.

I have looked at:

[How to use remote browsers for js-test-driver task on Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450457/how-to-use-remote-browsers-for-js-test-driver-task-on-jenkins)

https://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/GettingStarted

http://www.browserstack.com/automated-browser-testing-api
(fair pricing)

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/
(seems a bit dated)

Am I missing some currently recommended tools to use for CI and automation of browser compatibility testing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list that you can expand your search farther.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools

I've used Selenium, integrating it with Jenkins and it's worked well.